# Access the superclass of a Django Model

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

Given a Django Model

```
class Sub(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size_in_inches = models.IntegerField(default=6)

class TunaSub(Sub):
    fish_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Tuna")

class MeatballSub(Sub):
    meat_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Meatball with Cheese")
```

I would like to access the attribute of the superclass for, say a `__str__` method (in Python 3.x). How can I do so? Is this the correct solution?

```
class TunaSub(Sub):
    fish_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Tuna")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.super().name

class MeatballSub(Sub):
    meat_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Meatball with Cheese")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.super().name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you extend `Sub`, `name` is also a field of both `TunaSub` and `MeatballSub`. So you can simply use

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

As a side note, since you are extending a concrete model, you are in fact creating three separate tables in the database (named `sub`, `tuna_sub`, and `meatball_sub`) which are connected via one-to-one relations. If you only want to reuse the field definitions in `sub` and not actually create a table for it, use an [abstract base model class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, in fact, I am going to ask about the side question once more.

Comment: @bryansis2010 To restate; there is nothing with your current method but you are also physically separating the database tables. If you did not intend this behavior and only want to have two tables for your subclasses, then use an abstract `Sub` model. You should read the documentation I linked to for a more detailed discussion.