# Query superclass and have different logic for each subclass for Django models

Tags: django, oop, django-models

I am asking based on a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186370/access-the-superclass-of-a-django-model) about Django super-class and sub-classes.

Given I have a Food Item

```
class Food_Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

class TunaSub(Food_Item):
fish_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Tuna")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MeatballSub(Food_Item):
    meat_ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=20
      , default="Meatball with Cheese")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, say in my `views.py` I want to get all the food items, and based on the subclass, I want a different logic. For example:

```
total = 0
all_food_items = Food_Item.objects.filter(cost__gte=5)
for item in all_food_items:
  if #item == TunaSub:
     total = total + (item.cost*0.8) #there is a 20% discount
  elif #item == MeatballSub:
     total = total + (item.cost*0.75) #there is a 25% discount
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the `Sub` model? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: updated with the edited code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities depending on how your logic works:

If the discount is a property of the food item itself (as opposed to some other more complex logic), you can move the logic into the model:

```
class TunaSub(Food_Item):
    #...
    @property
    def cost_with_discount(self):
        return self.cost * 0.8  # You might even want to store this as a DB field...
```

Then in the view:

```
total = total + item.cost_width_discount
```

If the logic is more complex and depends on other temporal factors, then the approach you have already taken would work:

```
if item.__class__.__name__ == 'TunaSub':
    total = total + (item.cost*0.8) #there is a 20% discount
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is:

```
for item in all_food_items:
    if hasattr(item, "tunasub"):
        total = total + (item.cost * 0.8)
    elif hasattr(item, "meatballsub"):
        total = total + (item.cost * 0.75)
    ...
```

Comment: honestly, i'd be using a variant of both answers to help me but thank you all!